# Functional programming: Compare all items in an array

Tags: functional-programming, comparison, list

In functional programming, how do I do an equality comparison of all items in an array?

---

I have an array of items that I want to compare, for example for equality. Is it possible to use a fold (also known as reduce) operation for this?

This code won't work, because after the first iteration, memo is a boolean:

```
[a, b, c].reduce((memo, item) => memo === item)
```

I've tried this variant, which returns the last item if they are equal, but this is no good, since I need a boolean as the result:

```
[a, b, c].reduce((memo, item) => (memo === item) && item)
```

Forcing a boolean `!!` is no good either, since the item itself may be falsy and so give the wrong result.

I would like to have a functional solution to this problem – saving the result outside of the fold is much more verbose.

Comment: What language is this?  Furthermore, note that "why doesn't this code work" or "how do I do this in some language" are typically questions for Stack Overflow rather than Programmers.SE.

Comment: It's ECMAScript, but I'm interested in the general concept within functional programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21506025

Comment: Thanks, but I want to compare the items in a single array.

Comment: With what? ......

Comment: With each other.

Comment: So you want to know if all the elements are the same value?

Comment: What input and output are you expecting?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Exactly.

Comment: @MichaelT: ["a", "a", "a"] --> true, ["a", "a", "b"] --> false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266395

Comment: You nailed it, @RobertHarvey – thanks! Want to paste this in an answer?

Comment: Eh, I think that original post is suitably canonical.

Comment: One second... `[false, false, false]` should yield the value `true`

Comment: I should point out that in Scala or Clojure, one would do a different approach as there are different language built-ins. A variation on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224026) for Scala. There is no universal 'how to do this in functional programming' as each language has a slightly different dialect of tools available.

Comment: My bad, the reference answers it. Embarrassing....

Comment: Should I delete this question? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh well, the function suggested on StackOverflow returns `true` for `["false", ""]`. Guess the functional approach falls short here?

Comment: @dalgard I would contend that is more likely an issue with JavaScript than the functional approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I want to answer a small part of your question, that is nonetheless very interesting:

> Is it possible to use a fold (also known as reduce) operation for this?

Yes, it is.

In fact, it *is* always possible to use a fold for *anything*! Fold is a *general* operation for iteration, *anything* you can do with iteration, you can do with fold!

The [Wikipedia page for fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality) has a sketch of a proof for this, but I want to give another intuition thanks to a talk by [Rúnar Óli Bjarnason](http://blog.higher-order.com/) on [Functional Programming for Beginners](https://vimeo.com/18554216) which unfortunately seems to have vanished from the interwebs.

A collection can be either empty or not empty. The two arguments to fold tell it what to do when the collection is empty, and what to do with the next element when the collection is not empty. That covers all the cases, so it should be intuitively clear, that fold can do *anything*.

Another view, thanks to that same talk, is of fold as an interpreter. Think of a collection as a series of instructions. There are two kinds of instructions: the `HALT` instruction (which has no operands), and the `NEXT` instruction, which has one operand. The two arguments you supply to fold, are the two implementations of the interpreter functions for `HALT` and `NEXT`. Again, since there are only two instructions, and you supply the code for both of them, it comes as no surprise, that fold can do anything.

I actually put this to the test, and [re-implemented many of the methods from Ruby's collection framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834035/2988) (the `Enumerable` module), which normally rely *solely* on the `each` method (a `foreach`-style iterator which simply yields each element), so that they instead all rely on the `inject` method (which is how Ruby spells "fold").

So, what *does* it look like with a fold in ECMAScript?

```
someArray.reduce((memo, el, i, ary) => memo && ary[0] === el, true)
```

However, just because fold *can* do everything, it shouldn't be used for everything. When there are more appropriate, more specialized operations, these should be used instead:

```
someArray.every((el, i, ary) => ary[0] === el)
```

**Note:** technically speaking, these two implementations do not check whether every element is equal to every other element, they only check whether every element is equal to the first element. Thus, it relies on `===` being transitive and symmetric (as a well-behaved equality should be). If you cannot rely on that, you should first build the Cartesian Product of the array with itself, map it to whether the two elements are equal, and then ask if everything is true:

```
someArray.reduce((memo, el, _, ary) => memo.concat(ary.map(ell => [el, ell])), []).
map(([a, b]) => a === b).
every(el => el)
```

Comment: Side note: ECMAScript 2015 looks pretty nice, even to this Rubyist and Haskell aficionado!

Comment: It really, really is.

Comment: In ES2017 or whatever it will be called, the entire first line of the last example collapses to `[for (a of someArray) for (b of someArray) [a, b]]`

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have over 10 years of functional programming experience, and here's how I would do it:

1. If the sequence is empty, return true
2. Otherwise, return true if and only if all of the elements of the sequence are equal to the first one.

In Haskell, that starts out like this:

```
-- | Return false if and only if there is a pair of unequal elements
-- in the list.
allEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> a
allEqual [] = True
allEqual (first:rest) = all (\elem -> elem == first) rest
```

The `all` function tests whether all elements of a list satisfy a specified condition.  In this case, the condition is `(\elem -> elem == first)`—a function that tests whether the given `elem` is equal to `first`.

The `all` function is provided in [the `Data.List` library module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html), but let's implement it ourselves:

```
-- | Apply the given test to every element in the list, and return
-- false if and only if at least one element tests false.
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all test items = and (map test items)
```

To implement `all` I used two other standard functions—`map` and `and`.  But let's just go and implement them ourselves:

```
-- | Return true if and only if there are no `False` elements in the list
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and bools = foldr (&&) True bools

-- | Apply the given function to all elements of the list, collecting
-- the results in a list.
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr go []
  where go item rest = f item : rest
```

And those two functions I wrote in terms of `foldr` ("fold right"), which is one such "reduce" operation that you're interested in.  For completeness, let's write that function:

```
foldr :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (a:as) = f a (foldr f z as)
```

And now let me point out something very important that I did: **I wrote the function you wanted in terms of an utility function, that I then wrote in terms of two more utility functions, that I then wrote in terms of `foldr`, which I then wrote**.  And also, since the library provides all those utility functions, I could have just stopped at the first definition.

That's a key thing that newcomers to functional programming often overlook—reduce/fold is a *low level* operation that you use to write a large library of easier to use, auxiliary operations, and you break down your problems in terms of those.  Look for example at the large number of functions in [Haskell's `Data.List` library module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html).

The way you get good a functional-style list processing is to:

1. Learn how to break down problems in terms of library functions like those;
2. Learn how to write those library functions or new, similar ones that are missing from the library.

If you're always reaching for `reduce` right away you're going to end up with code that's harder to write and to read.  Whereas the reusable utility functions routinely cure this problem—the last line of my definition of `allEqual` basically reads like this: "test whether all elements after the first one in the list are equal to it."

Comment: It looks like you are missing a use of `items` in the definition of `map`. Should it not be `map f items = foldr go [] items`?

Comment: @Caleth: Well spotted. Fixed, but in a different manner than your suggestion (you can fix this either your way, or removing the use of `items` from the left hand side).

Answer (score 2):

Most FP languages I've seen have an implementation of `fold`/`reduce` which takes in a starting value for an accumulator, e.g. in Haskell:

```
pairs = zipWith (,) xs ys
foldl (\accum (x,y) -> (x == y) && accum) True pairs
---------------------------- initial value ^
```

There are also usually other functions which take care of calculations like this, such as `and`:

```
and [True,False,True,True,False] == False
```

Comment: ecmascript for and appears to be every

Comment: @jk it does indeed appear to be [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), thanks.